# Do Cognito Forms offer a Callback function?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any concept in the embedded mode where we can detect when a Cognito Form has been submitted? We want to use the submission as a trigger in our website. Either a callback on success or a callback on submission would be extremely useful.